# Can I access app engine service by using http protocol?

Tags: google-app-engine

I deployed a nodejs web server to `GAE` flexible environment.

When I access my web server, it using `https` protocol.

I try to use `http` protocol, but it seems can not be accessed.

Does `GAE` support `http`?

I expect both `http` and `https` should work fine.

**update 1**

`app.yaml`

```
runtime: nodejs8
env_variables:
  NODE_ENV: production
  PORT: 8080
```

`app.flex.yaml`

```
service: get-started-flex
runtime: nodejs
env: flex
env_variables:
  NODE_ENV: production
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

`server.js`

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const package = require('./package.json');

console.log('version: ', package.version);
console.log('process.env.NODE_ENV: ', process.env.NODE_ENV);

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send(`Hello from App Engine! version:${package.version}`);
});

app.get('/submit', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/views/form.html'));
});

app.post('/submit', (req, res) => {
  console.log({
    name: req.body.name,
    message: req.body.message
  });
  res.send('Thanks for your message!');
});

// Listen to the App Engine-specified port, or 8080 otherwise
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening on port ${PORT}...`);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In App Engine Standard you have the option to state the security of each handler by using the `secure` tag, however, in Flexible this is not possible.

Besides, in Flexible you can do `http` and `http` requests to the handlers but with [some restrictions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/go/how-requests-are-handled#unsupported_http_requests). Note that the application knows what protocol to use depending on the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header of the request, as you can see in [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/request-headers#app_engine-specific_headers).

However, I believe you can change this behaviour on the application level of your app. My guess is that you are enforcing `https` in some part of your application, for example, if you have the line `require("https")` in your application.

Also, I have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21961005/10561875) that could help in your case. If you disable SSL security checks in your handler, you might be able to process the requests even if the connection is not secure, but this will make your application insecure.

Comment: It seems app engine flexible environment does not support `wss`, https://stackoverflow.com/a/44557449/6463558, so I am looking for a way to using `http` in `GAE` flexible environment in order to using `ws://` instead of `wss://`. Just for testing. BTW, I am using `socket.io`. In my application, I did't use `https.createServer` or something. Just a simple http server

Comment: Can you share your code to take a look at it? It would also help me reproduce the issue.

Comment: Updated. Please take a look.

Comment: I found a reason. My company network use `websense `, so when I try to access my site using `http` protocol. I found there is a pending request in chrome `network` tab. `http://172.31.6.23:15871/cgi-bin/blockpage.cgi?ws-session=4127644080`. Because browser try to redirect to this `blockpage`, and for some reason, it can't be loaded. I will try it at home.